# HERE API Intermodal: Set / limit maximum distance or time to public transport

Tags: routes, here-api

The HERE Intermodal Routing API allows to walk/bike/drive to or from a public transport route. I have found a parameter to limit the maximum walk distance (pedestrian[maxDistance]). However I would love to set or limit the distance using bicycle or car. As a bonus a time limit would be great.
Has anyone found a hidden parameter or knows a way how to solve this?
I did try vehicle[maxDistance], but that does not exist or work.

Answer (score 0):

There are no such parameters. The API has via parameter with parkLate and parkEarly strategies. parkLate means that you want to go by car as far as possible and then a short public transit travel. parkEarly is vice versa.